# Nginx causes 301 redirect if there's no trailing slash

Tags: url, redirect, nginx

I'm running nginx in a Virtual Machine using NAT and I'm having redirection issues when I access it from the host machine.

#### Works as expected

- `http://localhost:8080/test/index.htm`: works.
- `http://localhost:8080/test/`: works.

#### Doesn't work as expected

- `http://localhost:8080/test`: redirects to `http://localhost/test/` . This is ***not*** what I want. **(notice it strips the port number)**

#### What I've tried

Based on what I've googled, I tried `server_name_in_redirect off;` and `rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;`, both with no success.

#### My default.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;
    
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    # rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
        root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files      $uri =404;
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }


    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 45):

I posted a possible solution to this problem on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/703184/12110); reproduced here for convenience:

If I understand the question correctly, you want to automatically serve, without using a 301 redirect, http://example.com/foo/index.html when the request is for http://example.com/foo with no trailing slash?

#### Basic solution that works for me

> If so I've found this try_files configuration to work:
>
> ```
> try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/ =404;
> ```
>
> - The first `$uri` matches the uri exactly
> - The second `$uri/index.html` matches a directory containing the index.html where the last element of the path matches the directory
>     name, with no trailing slash
> - The third `$uri/` matches the directory
> - The fourth `=404` returns the 404 error page if none of the preceding patterns match.

Taken from [Serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/703184/175181)

#### My updated version

If you add in the `server` block:

```
index index.html index.htm;
```

And modify `try_files` to look like this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

It should work too.

Comment: @maiconsanson - it seems to work for me with subfolders. Feel free to explain further.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, it works but the images inside the index.html are not found. By the way, I'm using to solve this with Dokku:

`if (-d $request_filename) {
    rewrite [^/]$ $scheme://$http_host$uri/ permanent;
}`

[buildpack-nginx](https://github.com/florianheinemann/buildpack-nginx/blob/master/bin/compile#L115)

Comment: It's likely that the relative paths in the index.html are broken somehow.  Inspect the url that the page is trying to retrieve, and compare with the url that the image is actually at, and see if the issue becomes clearer.

Comment: The urls is alright (`1.png` and so on). Everything is in the root app (index.html and images).

Comment: Upvote++ for try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/ =404; logic! it worked Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  note that my: ```location /apple-app-site-association {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.json;
        try_files $uri $uri/index.json $uri/ =404;
    }```

Comment: using `try_files` does not prevent the redirect for me. No matter what I try, nginx will redirect `/foo` to `/foo/`. Can anyone tell what I'm missing? here is my conf: https://gist.github.com/city41/26254ca3875144c153c90c4a8b1ad26a 

I resorted to `absolute redirect off;` and just accepted the redirect, but I'd love to avoid it if possible.
This nginx server is on heroku using their buildpack if that makes any difference.

Comment: Only `try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/ =404;` worked for me. The second solution did not.

Answer (score 44):

A somewhat simpler solution, that worked for me, is to disable absolute redirects with `absolute_redirect off;` as in the following example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;
    absolute_redirect off;

    location /foo/ {
        proxy_pass http://bar/;
    }
```

If I run curl on on `http://localhost:8080/foo`, I can see that the `Location` header in the redirect HTTP response is given as `/foo/` and not `http://localhost/foo/`.

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:8080/foo
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.13.8
Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 20:13:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: /foo/
```

From that, I assume any web-browser would do the right thing with the relative location. Tested on Chrome and it works fine.

Comment: This still returns a 301

Comment: Here's an explanation of the issue, and an actual solution: https://serverfault.com/a/812461

Comment: From my understanding the question is not actually complaining about the 301 itself. The 301 is fine, and expected, the problem is that the redirection should point to the same server name *keeping* the port 8080.

Comment: This works fine for me. For the extra paranoid, you can keep `absolute_redirect off` scoped to a `location {}` block if you just need it for that particular location

Comment: You only need `try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/ =404;` in your `server` block. But make sure you test it with `curl`. Browsers cache things. So if you hit the redirect once, it could keep doing that.

Comment: `absolute_redirect off` worked for me, Took many hours to figure out what's happening. My scenario is Angular app hosted in Nginx deployed in docker container having different host and container ports.

Comment: This is a working solution for most cases. For me, the server is behind a proxy that terminates SSL. without `absolute_redirect off;` NGINX always redirect to `http://` because it does not know the browser is using `https://`.

Comment: This solution is simple and works.  Going further, why is the default setting in nginx `absolute_redirect on`?   Wouldn't a relative redirect would be effective in all cases, whereas an absolute redirect is only correct sometimes, in the absence of proxies, CDNs, etc.

Answer (score 12):

try :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        if (-d $request_filename) {
            rewrite [^/]$ $scheme://$http_host$uri/ permanent;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try changing

```
server_name  localhost;
# server_name_in_redirect off;
```

to

```
server_name  localhost:8080;
server_name_in_redirect on;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove or move the `$uri/` option in try_files if you always will request the exact path of the URL. Remember has a correct definition of the default files in the folder with `index`. Ex:

```
index  index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/ /index.html;
```

If you need maintain `$uri/` in your configuration, only add the `$uri/index.html` before of the `$uri/` option, it's required to try the index before.

In this example the last option is show the content of `/index.html` instead of `=404` error

It's useful to the static pages generated like Docusaurus.