# nginx proxy_pass with arguments extra slash

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I want to forward requests to different apps that respond on different port numbers. The forward port number is based on the URL. For example, to access `localhost:5000/xxxx` I want to use `/p/5000/xxxx`, i.e.,

```
https://10.58.10.15/p/5000/jobs?id=0 ==> http://127.0.0.1:5000/jobs?id=0
```

I am using the following configuration:

```
location ~ ^/p/(\d+)/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$1/$2$is_args$args;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_set_header Host "$host/p/$1"; 
}
```

However, when I try the above link, it seems that the forward request is malformed. I am using curl to debug the proxy response. When I issue the following command:

```
curl -k -i https://10.58.10.15/p/5000/jobs?id=0
```

I receive the following answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Sun, 30 Apr 2017 23:46:14 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://10.58.10.15/p/5000/jobs/?id=0
```

As we can see there is an extra `/` between `jobs` and `?id=0`.
Is there anything wrong with my configuration? 
How am I suppose to debug my configuration? I have set nginx to debug logging, but from the messages it is hard to tell what is going on...

Comment: Is there another location block matching the URI, or could the service on 5000 be making the redirect?

Comment: no, that location is the only block matching the URI. Regarding the service on 5000, from the logs I see that it is a jetty server (9.2.), but I don't know if I can change the server behavior.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23859008/6229548