# Nginx make any URL work with or without a trailing slash

Tags: php, url, nginx, server, nginx-location

I want any directory to serve up either `index.html` or `index.php` – whether a trailing slash was given or not.

Right now my directories will load when a trailing slash **is** given, but not without.

```
# Works
localhost/mydirectory/

# Does not work
localhost/mydirectory
```

I just want it to work either way. Here is my nginx server block:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Your help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: see this. this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555428/nginx-causes-301-redirect-if-theres-no-trailing-slash?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Also, remove `$uri/` as it **causes** a rewrite.

Comment: @ManojJadhav That is how my server block is already setup, I see no major difference. I think the problem is without the trailing slash it thinks `mydirectory` is a file, not a directory.

Comment: @JustinBreen, were you able to get this resolved?