# Curl having problem to retrieve data after Nginx restart

Tags: nginx, curl

My server was working fine until I restarted the server and now my program with cURL API stops working. After troubleshooting for a long time, I figured out what the problem is.

When I use this command:

```
curl -i https://server.my-site.com/checkConnection
```

Nginx returns error:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 04 Jul 2019 17:14:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: /checkConnection/
```

but if I use this command:

```
curl -i -L https://server.my-site.com/checkConnection
```

Then the server return:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 04 Jul 2019 17:14:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: /checkConnection/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 04 Jul 2019 17:14:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

ok
```

And if I use a browser, then everything works. I have no clue what the error comes from. and how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A 301 response is not an error. You have to change the nginx configuration. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555428/nginx-causes-301-redirect-if-theres-no-trailing-slash

Comment: It was working before.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when the path maps to a directory. In theory, a URL like http://example.org/directory could map to a directory like `/wherever/public_html/directory`, and being a directory, show an `index.html` or similar file from there; however, that would cause surprising issues when you go to refer to other things like images in the same directory. `<img src="picture.jpg">` would load http://example.org/picture.jpg rather than http://example.org/directory/picture.jpg since it's relative to the URL the browser is actually viewing. Because of this, HTTP servers generally issue a redirect to add a slash at the end, which then both loads the right page *and* at a URL where relative paths do what humans expect.

Adding `-L` to your curl commandline causes it to follow the redirect, as browsers  do, and you get the result you were expecting. Without `-L`, curl is a more naive http client and lets you do what you will with the information.

Comment: thanks. but we are using django, every url pointed to a html file only.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a rule for `www.server.my-site.com` and that is why this is returning the 301 because it is redirecting from `server.my-site.com` to `www` site maybe you should share your configuration to check it

Comment: This happens a lot, but isn't what's happening in this case: The `Location:` header here is giving a URL that is not on a different hostname, but instead one relative to this hostname. Its behavior is more consistent with adding a slash for a path that maps to a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I finally fix it by adding an internal routing to uwsgi. Everything working fine now.