# nginx static directory, redirection 301 if no leading slash

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-301, static-files

I what to expose the content of a directory with nginx server.

I got the following `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` config:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}


http {
 server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  _;

    location ~ / {
       root /datahub/;
       autoindex on;
    }
 }
}
```

and the directory structure:

```
# ls -R /datahub/
/datahub/:
dir01

/datahub/dir01:
file.txt
```

### work:

- `curl http://192.168.6.65/dir01/`  (get directory listing)
- `curl http://192.168.6.65/dir01/file.txt`  (get file.txt content)

### does not work:

- `curl http://192.168.6.65/dir01` (301 redirect if the / is missing)

I saw the following link but I am not sure how to implement the solution for my case:
[Nginx causes 301 redirect if there's no trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555428/nginx-causes-301-redirect-if-theres-no-trailing-slash)

Any hints?

Comment: `index` and `autoindex` only work with URIs that point to a directory **and** have a trailing `/`. By default Nginx will add a trailing `/` by using a 301 redirect. If you don't have a trailing `/` the hyperlinks in the directory listing will not work properly.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Do you know if there exist a way for nginx to list the directory directly, without the redirect,  even if there is not trailing / ?

Comment: You can list the directory but the links will not work.